# how to generically open a form from another form?

Tags: c#

I have a total of 6 forms. In my mainForm, I have 5 buttons to open the other forms inside the panel. what i know is something like this:

```
 form1 f1 = new form1();
 f1.TopLevel = false;
 f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 this.panelMid.Controls.Add(f1);
 f1.show();
```

now, since I have 5 other forms, I want to make a function that would make me open the forms without re-typing those code in every button event. 
My problem is that I don't know to pass the form into a function as parameter.

Comment: Your "problem" doesn't make any sense. You're passing a form as a function parameter in `this.panelMid.Controls.Add(f1);`

Comment: There is such a thing as a `UserControl` which would make much more sense than a form for what you are playing at.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, its bcoz want to open/show the form inside the panel.

Comment: @Plutonix, any recommendations ?

Comment: I realize that, but you state that your problem is that you don't how to do what you just did. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, i want to have a function that would let me just pass the form name that i want to open and then execute those code above but in generic. like what if form2 will now to open, so what i want is to just call the function then pass the form2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRY 101, based on your code, with some generics chucked in

```
public void MyAwesomeFormShower<TForm>()
   where TForm : Form, new()
{
   var form = new TForm();
   // common code here
   form.TopLevel = false;
   form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   ///this.panelMid.Controls.Add(f1); // < who knows what this does, however don't do it
   form.Show();
}
```

**Usage**

```
MyAwesomeFormShower<MyLovelyHorseForm>();
```

---

Or if you want to get fancy

```
public void MyAwesomeFormShower<TForm>(Action<TForm> action = null) 
   where TForm : Form, new()   
{
   var form = new TForm();
   // common code here
   form.TopLevel = false;
   form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

   action?.Invoke();
   form.Show();
}
```

**Usage**

```
MyAwesomeFormShower<MyLovelyHorseForm>();

// or

MyAwesomeFormShower<MyLovelyHorseForm>((form) => 
     {   
         // Specialised form stuff here
         // that is specific to MyLovelyHorseForm
     });
```

Comment: build errors sir, the 1st and 2nd block of code. lots of red line

Comment: do i need to add something into the namespace sir ?

Comment: @Plutonix. not a good welcome to newbies. of course i can't explain well.

Comment: @MichaelRandall, updated code works well sir. thank you.

Comment: @princevezt Not so new - you've been a member for 2.5 years.  It doesnt take a lot of any kind of experience to  know that red lines represent errors and the smart kids might need to know what those errors are  to be able to help.  You wouldnt call your mechanic and tell him your car *makes lots of bad noise* would you (and expect any sort of informed help)?

Comment: @Plutonix. yeah okay. my bad. sorry